# DateTime()->sub/add vs DateTime->modify

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

I am writing code that will do 3 queries to select items that expire within 30 days, 60 days and 90 days:

```
$arrDates = array("30"=>array(), "60"=>array(), "90"=>array());
$sDateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
$sQuery = "SELECT *
            FROM `table
            WHERE `expiry_date` BETWEEN "; // Ranges will be added later

foreach ($arrDates as $sInterval=>$arrContainer)
{
    $dtStart = new DateTime();
    $dtEnd = new DateTime();
    $sRangeStart = $dtStart->add(new DateInterval("P{$sInterval}D"))->format("{$sDateFormat} 00:00:00");
    $sRangeEnd = $dtEnd->add(new DateInterval("P{$sInterval}D"))->format("{$sDateFormat} 23:59:59");

    $arrDates[$sInterval] = fetch_all($sQuery . "'{$sRangeStart}' AND '{$sRangeEnd}'");
}
```

This code works without any issues. A colleague has suggested that I replace the code inside the foreach loop
with the following:

```
$dtStart = new DateTime();
$dtEnd = new DateTime();
$dtStart->modify("+{$sInterval} days")->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format("{$sDateFormat} 00:00:00");
$dtEnd->modify("+{$sInterval} days")->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format("{$sDateFormat} 23:59:59");

$arrDates[$sInterval] = fetch_all($sQuery . "'{$sRangeStart}' AND '{$sRangeEnd}'");
```

His reasoning behind this change being that it would mean not having to instantiate 2 DateIntervals every loop.
I do not agree with his reasoning mainly because ->modify is an older way of date modification, and I'm not 100%
convinced that his way would mean an increase in performance (even though the performance hit we would take either way
would be negligible).

If anyone could provide evidence for which way is better (either way is welcome), I'd be most grateful!

Comment: I would think that the processing time/resources expended on either method of dealing with the DateTime objects would be a drop in the bucket compared with executing the queries and returning their results.

Comment: This is entirely true, and the basis of the whole argument is kind of silly, but I want to use the newer `add` function rather than the `modify` function, and "it's the new way to do it" doesn't seem to be a good enough reason for him, so I'm looking for other advantages or disadvantages to look at.

Comment: `.add()` and `.sub()` aren’t _so much_ newer. They were added in 5.3 while `.modify()` was added in 5.2 . Two other points: (a) Why did you call `setTime()` in the second version, but not the first? (b) If you’re really worried about efficiency, you should use a prepared statement, so that the database doesn’t have to repeatedly parse the SQL statement.

Comment: @Manngo this was a really long time ago, I don't recall if there was any need to setTime, or why it was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both ways are pretty the same, it's a matter of taste how to write code.

For my taste `$dt->modify('+5 days')` is more readable than `$dt->add(new DateInterval("P5D"))`

As for performance, below is a code to test it and results are:

> $dt->modify('+5 days') - 0.0503 sec
>
> $dt->add(new DateInterval("P5D")) - 0.0572 sec

so, the readable code is also a *very little* faster one for the case from the question :)

```
<?php

    $i = 0;
    $start = microtime(true);
    while($i++ < 10000) {
        $date = new DateTime('2018-02-13');
        $date->modify('+5 days');
    }
    $end = microtime(true);

    echo $end - $start, "\n";

    $i = 0;
    $start = microtime(true);
    while($i++ < 10000) {
        $date = new DateTime('2018-02-13');
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
    }
    $end = microtime(true);

    echo $end - $start, "\n";
```

Comment: We're talking micro-optimizations, but your example with DateTinterval is slower because you create a new DateInterval object each time. It's faster if you create the object outside of the loop.

Comment: Good catch! :) You're right, it's faster without creating an object inside a loop.

Comment: @WayFarer It looks like DateTime::modify ignores DST, so, no they are not the same. DateTime::add behaves correctly in this case.

Comment: @EugeneK I don’t understand what you mean about ignoring DST. If I use `.modify('1 day')` it certainly adds 24 hours during DST. It also adds 24 hours when the 1 day spans a change in DST.

Answer (score 0):

But without `setTime()` is not the same?

```
$dtStart = new DateTime();
$dtEnd = new DateTime();
$dtStart->modify("+{$sInterval} days")->format("{$sDateFormat} 00:00:00");
$dtEnd->modify("+{$sInterval} days")->format("{$sDateFormat} 23:59:59");
$arrDates[$sInterval] = fetch_all($sQuery . "'{$sRangeStart}' AND '{$sRangeEnd}'");
```